# Obtener valor parámetro out de procedimiento mysql desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

Buenas noches,

Tengo una duda, no se como hacerlo:
Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en Mysql, con parámetros de entrada y uno de salida, lo que quiero es que después de enviar los parámetros de entrada, capturar el mensaje del parámetro de salida, pero no encuentra información puntual sobre esto.

Gracias.

Comment: Con `PDO` en la [documentación  ofrece ejemplos sencillos para esto](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Habia Olvidado mencionar, estoy usando mysqli, gracias

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, revisare la ultima respuesta, pero en realidad, me funciono esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969465/stored-procedures-and-prepared-statements-ins-php-mysqli Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto en mysqli.

```
<?php
//Nos conectamos a la base de datos
$mysqli = new mysqli("ejemplo.com", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    //Si ocurre algun error en el intento de coneccion 
    //realizamos alguna accion
    echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
//Verificamos que el procedimiento no exista,
//Creamos el procedimiento con dos parametros (IN) de entrada y uno de
//salida (OUT). Dicho procedimiento solo concatena los dos parametros de
//entrada y los coloca en el parametro de salida. 
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_test") ||
    !$mysqli->query('CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test(IN param_uno VARCHAR(10), IN param_dos VARCHAR(10),OUT param_tres VARCHAR(20)) BEGIN SELECT param_uno + param_dos INTO param_tres; END;')) {
    //Si ocurre un error realizamos una acción
    echo "Falló la creación del procedimiento almacenado: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//Preparamos la consulta pasando los valores 'A' y 'B' a los 
//Parametros de entrada
if (!$mysqli->query("SET @param_uno = 'A',@param_dos = 'B'") || !$mysqli->query("CALL proc_test(@param_uno,@param_dos)")) {
     //Si ocurre un error realizamos una acción
    echo "Falló CALL: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

//Rellenamos la variable $resultado, realizando la consulta.
if (!($resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT @param_tres as p_out"))) {
    //Si ocurre un error realizamos una acción
    echo "Falló la obtención: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
//Definimos que nuestro resultado lo trataremos como un array asociativo.
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

//Imprimimos el resultado.
echo $fila['p_out'];
?>
```

Comment: cual es la explicación de este código, recuerda que es una de las razones para voto negativo el agregar únicamente código. Realiza únicamente una respuesta y puedes agregar actualizaciones en la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto el codigo.

```
$sql="CALL proc_test($param_uno,$param_dos)";

            $rs = mysql_query($sql,$dbc);

            if($rs){
              //Lo llenas como objeto puedes 
                usar mysql_fetch_array tambien.

                $re = mysql_fetch_object($rs);  

                $ret = $re->param_tres;

            }else{
                $error = mysql_error();
            }
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero en no comprendo si en el ejemplo que compartes, lo devuelve como parametro, o solo devuelve un set de datos, supongamos o hagamos el ejemplo, este seria mi proc:

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_test`(in param_uno varchar(10),
       in param_dos varchar(10),
       out param_tres varchar(10))
BEGIN
 set param_tres = concat(param_uno, param_dos);
END

Comment: ¿Usas PDO para la consulta? Porque cambia la sintaxis.